# How to execute a for loop operation really fast for a large dataset

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scalability

I am using Twitter's ro-BERTa base for sentimental analysis:

[Sentimental Analysis](https://huggingface.co/cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment)

I was able to follow the above tutorial and completed the job. The problem however is to to make it run for millions of records. It is really slow and runs for over an hour. Is there a way we can get this faster?

Code:

```
temp = df.copy()

for k in range(100):
    text = df.data[k]
    text = preprocess(text)
    encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
    output = model(**encoded_input)
    scores = output[0][0].detach().numpy()
    scores = softmax(scores)
    for i in range(scores.shape[0]):
        l = labels[i]
        s = scores[i]
        temp.loc[k, 'Negative']= np.round(scores[0],4)
        temp.loc[k, 'Neutral']= np.round(scores[1],4)
        temp.loc[k, 'Positive']= np.round(scores[2],4)
```

I am able to store the sentiments in different columns but my dataframe is too large and as you see I am running it only for first 100 rows whereas in reality I have over 1000K rows and it is really slow. I want to run if for

```
for k in range(len(df)):
    <loop body>
```

How do I make it run faster. Can we break the df into chunks of 10K (or 1K) and run 100 such operations parallelly and get the final output for all the rows in a quick time?

Comment: This looks like a fun project! But I am not sure it fits within [Stack Overflow guidelines for questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which tend to favor questions about specific problems rather than hypothetical ones. How about you try to parallelize your program and come back to modify your question if you run into issues?

Comment: It looks like these two for-loops are pretty dependent on each other based on the variable names and definitions. So this might be as good as it gets. One thing you could do to make it go faster is if you split df.data into 4 parts then processed all the data at the same time using threads then you might get a 4x faster result. I'm not sure if you could do that however.

Comment: I am not much aware of the parallel processing and I was reading about it and also saw some stackoverflow answers but unable to make it work. Just need an approach to begin with on how to parallelize. Breaking it into multiple dataframes is something I tried but I need to do it in real time.

Comment: `temp.loc[k, 'Negative']` is set `scores.shape[0]` times for no apparent reasons. Only the last value is important. Note that `loc` is very slow and should never be used in a big loop. Pandas/Numpy vectorized functions should be used instead.

Comment: I need all the three ratios for later analysis Jerome. Hence, I had to store them. Is there a better way you suggest?